# Errors in Bais Hamikdosh administration

Tags: sources-mekorot, mistakes, beis-hamikdash

Am interested in locating as many clear places in Mishnayas and Gemorro that refers to administrative problems in the Bais Hamikdash and how handled
e.g. Yoma and error in determining time for the morning korbon

Has anyone written a book on this topic?

Comment: Anything going wrong with the avoda

Comment: I think it's a mishna in Yoma

Comment: Yes, it's a mishna in Yoma discussing the implementation of the "Barkai" announcement. There aren't that many similar instances in the mishna. Are we including things like the institution of a lottery to determing the privilege for participating in the sacrifices, which came after the old "race to the top" method resulted in injuries?